# Sencha touch 2 - how to override the nestedlist tap event for a custom component

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I am using getItemTextTpl to add a checkbox component to a nested list - I would also like to be able to override the default tap event so that when the checkbox is checked a popup message shows and the list does not advance to the next items. Please see below for my configuration - I am able to capture the checkbox check event but do not no how to override the default behavior for nestedlist. Thanks for your help and please let me know if I can clarify any details - if it helps I am using sencha architect

Nestedlist config:

```
getItemTextTpl: function(recordnode) {
        return '<table width="100%"><row>' + 
        '<tr><td width="100%" align="left" width="100%" valign="bottom"><div class="view"><input type="checkbox" <tpl  if="done">checked</tpl> />&nbsp;&nbsp;{name}</td></row></table>'; 

    }
```

Controller:

```
onNestedlistInitialize: function(component, options) {
// setup taskList to listen on the tap on the checkbox and show a popup window 
component.element.on({
    tap: function(e, el) {
        console.log('checkbox tapped'); 
        //need to override nestedlist tap event and show popup message
    }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you try to override the itemtap event ?

Comment: @TDeBailleul I have overrides in place to capture if record.isLeaf() or not, but how do I prevent the list from advancing through the tree when the checkbox is selected?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the list from switching to the next card you need to override the activeitemchange like so :

```
var nestedList = Ext.create('Ext.NestedList', {
  ...
  listeners:{
    activeitemchange:function(){
      if(...){ // Check if you checkbox is checked or not
         return false; // return false prevent the nestedlist from switching to the next view
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I set up an activeItemChange event in Architect to override the list switching as you've shown, but still need somehow to capture the tap event of the checkbox (or button or other form element on the list item) before return false on the list movement. In your example you are showing a check of whether it is checked, but shouldn't it be a check of whether it is tapped (might also include the checkbox and label on the list item)? Thanks again for your help in figuring this out